# How to restrict user inputs?

Tags: python

For example a program has the line:

```
user_input = raw_input(" enter : ")
```

How do you make it so that the program will only continue once what the user enters are letters only? And is he enter anything else he will get an error.

EDIT: Thanks for the help but it says try again if there is a space. The solution is:

```
while True:
    name = raw_input("Enter name : ")
    if name.replace(' ', '').isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print "Try again"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input(" enter: ")
    if user_input.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print "try again"
```

Comment: Thanks you so much ! i had tried everything i could think of and it still wouldn't work

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark :-)

Comment: yeah i will but it doesn't let me, I will have to wait

Answer (score 2):

Just use `str.isalpha()`:

```
user_input = ""
while not user_input.isalpha():
    user_input = raw_input(" enter : ")
```

Comment: @kindall I already edited my answer.  I noticed that, too ;)